# Magento Contact form error

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am running a multi store magento application enterprise 1.14.1.0.

For one store, the contact form is not working. When submitting the contact us form it says "Unable to submit your request, please try again later".

This issue is not happening for other stores.

Order confirmation emails are also not being sent. Back-end configurations are correctly set.

Comment: is this happening on a secure url (https) or non-secure ?

Comment: It is non-secure @JeffreydeGraaf

Comment: Look at this: http://inchoo.net/magento/problems-with-contact-form/ .. try not to change the core files though.

Comment: Actually I have read this. If this is the issue, then the error should happen for the other store also.

Comment: @ManafPM Okay, all stores have the same design package? Perhaps it's a missing form key?